# Python list class seems to have entangled indices

Tags: python, arrays

I'm new to python and am experiencing some unexpected behavior in my first project.

I made a class that turns a dictionary of coordinates into a list. It seemed to be working fine until I tried changing the coordinates after its initialization.

I want to shift all the coordinates along one index (index 1 goes to 2, 0 goes to 1) and put a new coordinate in index 0. However, when I change index 0 after shifting the rest along, index 1 is also changed.

```
some_coords = [{'x': 0, 'y': 0}, {'x': 1, 'y': 0}, {'x': 1, 'y': 1}]

class coord:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

class coord_list:
    def __init__(self):
        self.body = [coord(some_coords[i].get('x'), some_coords[i].get('y')) for i in range (len(some_coords))]


snake = coord_list()

print("printing original snake coordinates")
for i in range(len(snake.body)):
    print(f"At index {i}: x : {snake.body[i].x}, y : {snake.body[i].y} ")

print("shifting all indexes forward, except index 0")
for i in range(len(snake.body) -1, 0, -1):    
    snake.body[i] = snake.body[i-1]

print("printing snake coordinates")
for i in range(len(snake.body)):
    print(f"At index {i}: x : {snake.body[i].x}, y : {snake.body[i].y} ")

print("moving index 0 to x : 0, y : 1")
snake.body[0].y += 1

print("printing snake coordinates")
for i in range(len(snake.body)):
    print(f"At index {i}: x : {snake.body[i].x}, y : {snake.body[i].y} ")
```

Output:

```
printing original snake coordinates
At index 0: x : 0, y : 0
At index 1: x : 1, y : 0
At index 2: x : 1, y : 1
shifting all indexes forward, except index 0
printing snake coordinates
At index 0: x : 0, y : 0
At index 1: x : 0, y : 0
At index 2: x : 1, y : 0
moving index 0 to x : 0, y : 1
printing snake coordinates
At index 0: x : 0, y : 1
At index 1: x : 0, y : 1
At index 2: x : 1, y : 0
```

Why are the y values at both index 0 and 1 changed after modifying index 0, and is there a way to avoid this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assigning an object doesn't make a copy of it. So after the shift, `snake.body[0]` and `snake.body[1]` both refer to the same `coord` object. When you modify the `x` attribute of that object, it's reflected in both indexes.

To solve this problem, you need to make new objects:

```
for i in range(len(snake.body) -1, 0, -1):    
    snake.body[i] = coord(snake.body[i-1].x, snake.body[i-1].y)
```